# Save London From a Sudden Glacial Melting?

Tags: underwater

There are a few million cubic miles of water trapped in the ice-caps that line our planet's poles. If all of it were to melt in a matter of a few short years (somehow), London [would surely be left under the new sea-level](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2013/09/rising-seas/if-ice-melted-map).

Quick facts: Trafalgar square has a [21m elevation](http://elevationmap.net/trafalgar-square-london-wc2n-uk?latlngs=(51.5084186,-0.12822570000002997)) relative to the present sealevel. If all the ice covering Antarctica, Greenland, and in mountain glaciers around the world were to melt, sea level would rise about 70 meters (230 feet).

[image: london bloob bloob]

**What can be done to save London, lest Big Ben is to sound its bells underwater? Can Britannia once again rule the waves?**

Comment: So in this scenario, how deep are the main streets of London going to be below the new sea level.  Say Trafalgar Square.

Comment: If all that ice melted I think we'd have much bigger problems on our hands than trying to save London - the climate of our world would be such that I'm not sure which parts of the planet would still be inhabitable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I suspect that such an event will cause such widespread devastation that we would be in a mode of 'trying to survive an apocalypse'.  Large areas will try to do the Netherlands thing and build walls to hold back the Ocean as much as possible.  But to do that in any kind of timely and useful manor, first you need to know how high  the water is going to go and how much time you have to deal with it.

Then you take your topographic maps and see how large an area you need to enclose with a wall to protect everything from that point on.  We are talking of building a tall wall hundreds of miles long, with the need to hold back an Ocean worth of water.

Now with a 70m increase in ocean depth, that would put Trafalgar Square 150 below the new surface.  Wall bases at the street level would need to sustain [65 lbs/sq in.](http://www.kylesconverter.com/pressure/feet-of-water-to-pounds-per-square-inch).  That is quite a bit.  So on top of building a wall 175 feet tall(need to have some protection from waves!) to hold back the ocean, support it on ground that is Swiss cheese, close up the tunnels that would lead outside the walls, construct pumps that can move the Themes volume up and over the wall (at a rate to keep up with the drainage).   And the fact that rain will likely increase with higher evaporation due to lower salt in the oceans, there will be more water to pump.

So I think you won't save London without starting decades ahead of time and even there would be the most impressive feat of engineering taken on by humans.

The Good news is that Big Ben is 316' tall, so a good 150 feet will stick out of the ocean waves and it won't be tolling under water!

Now Saving specific areas of London *might* work if they want to build inverted 'swimming' pools around things like Windsor Palace, Parliament etc.  But I think most agree that it would be a terrible waste of resources that could be used to save much more of the country side for livable land for the survivors.

So Big Ben will ring out in the clear air as long as it has power and until the Ocean erodes it base and it collapses.  However if the current tall buildings are reinforced to handle being half flooded, they could still be used as living quarters or offices, since many will still reach well above the new sea level.

Comment: upvoted for the good news on big ben